# Are there any wrong with my python version?

Tags: python, datetime

when I input python code:

```
today=datetime.datetime.now()
toda
today.weekday(),
```

Result is:

```
datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 18, 16, 53, 35, 124836)    
1
```

But, should it be 2? Anything wrong or my mistake?

Comment: Today is Tuesday, the weekday 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, today is Tuesday, and that's [weekday 1](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday), following the documentation:

> Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. The same as `self.date().weekday()`. See also`isoweekday()`.

So Monday is `0`, Tuesday is `1`, etc.

If you want `2` for Tuesday, use [`.isoweekday()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoweekday) instead:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().isoweekday()
2
```

> Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 1 and Sunday is 7. The same as `self.date().isoweekday()`. See also `weekday()`, `isocalendar()`.

Answer (score 6):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html),

> Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. For example, `date(2002, 12, 4).weekday() == 2`, a Wednesday. See also `isoweekday()`.